# How do I deal with INSERT parameters which may be null, but are also converted?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, insert

So, normally, I would write something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GROSS_COMP_INCOME", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[4]));
```

However, when run on data that is missing I would have difficulty in the `Convert.ToDouble` part of the code as I cannot convert `DBNull` into `Double` type. I know this now.

However, taking that out, getting the values of the datagridview into the database would alert me that it is of the incorrect datatype (alerted by the NON-blank values)because I did not convert the data.

So, I want to convert the data but cannot convert `DBNULL`, and I want to insert possibly null data but cannot insert raw data from the data grid view.

At this point I don't know how to proceed.

---

Database: MsAccess.

Datagridview data is pulled from an excel file but becomes independent as a row in the DGV.

Comment: Why don't you try a validation before like this: double number = -1; Double.TryParse(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[4], out number);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GROSS_COMP_INCOME", number);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GROSS_COMP_INCOME", DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[4] == null ? System.DbNull : Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[s].Cells[4]));
```